# Infinite length array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I noticed one thing in `Haskell` that it efficiently handle working with infinite length array with great ease.

So being swift programmer, **I am curious about how we can achieve this with swift?**
For example:

```
var infiniteArray = [1,2,3,.............]
```

Comment: You say Haskell has infinite length arrays but what exactly does that mean? Define exactly what you are looking for or else people will fill in their (possibly incorrect) interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swift's `Array` stores concrete, eagerly evaluated elements, so it can't be infinite (due to finite memory).

The Swift equivalent is an infinite `Sequence`. Here's an example that produces the an infinite sequence of natural numbers.

```
let naturalNumbers = sequence(first: 0, next: { $0 + 1 })
let first5NaturalNumbers = Array(naturalNumbers.prefix(5))

print(first5NaturalNumbers)
```

It uses the [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence) function to produce an [`UnfoldSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unfoldsequence), which is an infinitely long, lazy evaluated sequence.

Comment: *Collections* have a start index, end index, and therefore a finite length.

Comment: @MartinR Fair point!

Comment: have tried for number 5000000. It took considerable amount of time.

Comment: What do you mean? You tried to get the first 5000000 elements using `prefix(_:)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Haskell has lazy evaluation because it is a fully functional language (has no side effects, etc.), Swift is not a functional language (though it borrows some features, functionality and syntax) and does not have the same features.

That being said you can use `Sequence`s and `Generator`s to create the impression of infinite lists - see http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/06/26/swift-sequences.html for example. Of course the list is not really infinite - btw the Haskell list isn't infinite either, it just stores the function to create new entries.

The main difference is that in Haskell there are some major performance optimisations possible due to the lack of variables and side effects. In Swift you cannot do that. So be careful translating Haskell code to Swift.

Comment: Although Swift isn’t purely a functional language it can indeed follow many functional paradigms with optimization and few compromises. What optimizations are you referring to when you say that Haskell has them and Swift lacks them? Swift can store the function to create new entries, just as Haskell does.

Comment: @ColGraff for example that multiple invocations of the same method result in the same guaranteed output. That enables Haskell to evaluate each expression only once and use the return value in every place the call occurs, in Swift that is not possible. `a() + a()` would cause Haskell to evaluate `a` once and replace both calls with the return value, Swift has to call `a` actually two times.

Comment: @ColGraff which is especially important for any expensive methods calls which include some kind of exponential growth in their computation like generating fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Your two statements seem to contradict each other. On one hand you want a function that doesn’t evaluate each time and on the other you want a function that does. Can you give an example of a fibonacci generator that doesn’t get evaluated every time it’s called, as you are saying here?

Comment: @ColGraff are you familiar with Haskell? Basically if you have a function `a(n) -> n = 0 || n == 1 ? 1 : a(n-1) + a(n-2)` and you want to evaluate `a(100)` it will unfold to `a(100) = a(99) + a(98) = a(98) + a(97) + a(97) + a(96) = ...`. At this place Haskell is able to replace two calls to `a(97)` with only one call and using the return value twice. Swift cannot do that and has to actually evaluate the entire call stack for `a(97)` twice which is extremely expensive (the branching is horrible for this method)

Comment: I am not overly familiar with Haskell, just some general knowledge of how it works. I think I see the optimization you’re talking about but I wonder if the same could be done easily in Swift. I’ll have to check it out.

Comment: @ColGraff that cannot be done because Swift has variables, it has state. There is no guarantee that two invocations of `a(97)` will *actually* return the same result. Haskell has no state, it has no variables - there is no way for `a(97)` to return two different values. (not considering IO of course)

Comment: seems this topic is getting interesting than I  have expected.

Comment: "if the same could be done easily in Swift" it _could_ be done, the compiler could mark functions that have no side effects (incl any calls it makes), and apply the same optimizations Haskell does.  As of late 2019 it doesn't, and that isn't on any public plans.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention to pass unknown number of parameters to a function (*from a logical viewpoint, you can't say "infinite number of parameters" because of the limitation of the machine's memory*), it's called *[variadic parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)*:

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.
>   You use a variadic parameter to specify that the parameter can be
>   passed a varying number of input values when the function is called.
>   Write variadic parameters by inserting three period characters (...)
>   after the parameter’s type name.

For example, let's say that you want to implement a function that takes unknown number of Ints to sum them:

```
func summationOfInfiniteInts(ints: Int...) -> Int {
    return ints.reduce(0, +)
}

let summation = summationOfInfiniteInts(ints: 1, 2, 3, 4) // 10
```

Note that `ints` parameter in the block of `summationOfInfiniteInts`  represented as `[Int]` (array of `Int`).

Hope this helped.

Comment: I was searching this using variable length args keywords in swift, nice plus one.

Comment: @vaibhav glad to help, for more information, I recommend  to check [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) - *Variadic Parameters* section

Comment: yes, you are right. But that is valid for function parameter only.

Comment: thanks sure i will check, its just because of java bg nothing else :)

Comment: @BlackTiger yup. Because I couldn't figure what's your exact purpose to use it, so I assumed that this is what are you looking for :)